# How to check if a laravel validator response is an error or not with Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel 7 and Vue.js 2.

I make a delete call with axios and if everything is correct I receive as a response the new data in the related tables to update a select and if there is an error I receive the errors of the Laravel validator.

The problem is that I have to understand with javascript if the response is an error or not... but I don't know how to do that.

This is my Vue component:

```
<template>
    <form method="DELETE" @submit.prevent="removeTask">
        <div class="form-group">
            <title-form v-model="titleForm" :titleMessage="titleForm"></title-form>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tasks">Tasks:</label>
            <select required v-model="user.tasks" class="form-control" id="tasks" @mouseover="displayResults(false, false)">
                <option v-for="task in tasks_user" :value="task.id" :key="task.id">
                    {{ task.task_name }} - {{ task.task_description }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <validated-errors :errorsForm="errors" v-if="displayErrors===true"></validated-errors>
            <!--<success-alert :success_message="successMessage" v-if="displaySuccess===true"></success-alert>-->
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    import ValidatedErrors from "./ValidatedErrors.vue"
    import SuccessAlert from "./SuccessAlert.vue"
    import TitleForm from "./TitleForm.vue"

    export default {
        components: {
            'validated-errors': ValidatedErrors,
            'success-alert': SuccessAlert,
            'title-form': TitleForm
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        },
        props: {
            tasks_user: {
                type: Array,
                required: true,
                default: () => [],
            }
        },
        computed: {
            titleForm: function () {
                return "Remove a task from " + this.tasks_user[0].user_name;
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                user: {
                    tasks: ""
                },
                errors: {},                
                displayErrors: false,
                displaySuccess: false,
                successMessage: "The task has been removed."
            }
        },
        methods: {
            removeTask: function() {
                alert(this.user.tasks);
                //axios.delete('/ticketsapp/public/api/remove_task_user?id=' + this.user.tasks)
                axios.delete('/ticketsapp/public/api/remove_task_user?id=' + 101)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if(typeof response.data[0].task_id !== "undefined") {
                        alert("There are no errors.");
                    } else {
                        alert("There are errors.");
                    }
                    if (typeof response.data[0].task_id === "undefined") { //problem
                        alert('noviva');
                        console.log(response.data);
                        this.errors = response.data;
                        this.displayErrors = true;
                    } else {
                        alert('viva');
                        this.tasks_user = response.data;
                        this.errors = {};
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert(noooooo);
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },
            displayResults(successShow, errorShow) {
                this.displayErrors = errorShow;
                this.displaySuccess = successShow;
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

This is my method in the controller:

```
public function remove(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'id' => 'required|exists:task_user,id'
    ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response($validator->errors()); //problem
    } 

    $task_user_id = $request->id;

    $user_id = TaskUser::where('id', $task_user_id)->pluck('user_id')->first();

    TaskUser::find($task_user_id)->delete();

    $tasks_user = TaskUser::with(['user', 'task'])->get();

    $tasks_user = TaskUser::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    $tasks_user = TaskUserResource::collection($tasks_user);

    return json_encode($tasks_user);
}
```

To distinguish the type of return I created this condition: `if (typeof response.data[0].task_id === "undefined")` but when that condition is true everything falls down and I receive the following error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: noooooo is not defined

So how can I do to distinguish the type of return of the API call?

Comment: Why are you passing request data to a DELETE endpoint? You should delete a resource by sending a DELETE request to that resource’s URL. You then know if the resource was deleted by whether you get a 2xx status code back, or a 4xx/5xx status code.

Comment: Uhm I am not expert about API methods. Are you suggesting me to change the method to POST, attach a status code in the controller response and use that code in JavaScript to understand if the validator fails?

Comment: Absolutely not. I’m saying if you have a DELETE endpoint, then a request to that URL should delete the resource identified by that URL.

Comment: Yep but it makes that in `TaskUser::find($task_user_id)->delete()`... in my case maybe should do two different api calls one to delete that `task_user_id` and one to retrieve the new updated table? If you want you can try an answer.